# Teradata SQL parameter syntax

Tags: sql, parameters, teradata

Is there syntax which allows a parameter marker in the middle of a table name? For example, consider the queries

```
    sel * from t?x
```

and

```
    sel * from t?x_blah.
```

Both execute as

```
    sel * from t1
```

if the user inputs 1. In the first query `x = 1` and in the second query `x_blah = 1`. I would like to modify the second query to set `x = 1` and execute as

```
    sel * from t1_blah.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A question mark parameter marker can only be used for data values, not object names.  So, the short answer is no.

Here's some info from Teradata:[Clicky!](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/tomnolan/2012/01/question-mark-parameter-markers)

Answer (score 1):

What's your client tool?

SQL Assistant supports parameters for object names, but there's no way to get the expected behavior (as you probably noticed).

The only solution might be using Dynamic SQL within a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I'm using SQL Assistant but, unfortunately, I don't have create procedure privileges.

Answer (score 0):

A `?` works in Teradata SQL Assistant.  It will ask you to enter the parameter:

`select ?x from ?y;`

When you run it, SQL Assistant will ask you for the parameters x and y.  If you put 10 instances of `?x` in your code, SQL Assistant will only ask for x once.

Comment: That's correct, but doesn't answer the original question *Is there syntax which allows a parameter marker **in the middle** of a table name?*